# RuntimeException: /vendor/emarref/jwt/src/Encryption/Asymmetric.php:35 during crontab execution, ok at shell

Tags: php, cron, jwt

I have a script that is on a cronjob, that works run fine when I run it from the shell.

However, when it runs from the crontab schedule if fails to run, I've managed to narrow down to problem to here:

```
$privateKey = openssl_get_privatekey('file://private.key.pem', $passphrase);
$encryption->setPrivateKey($privateKey);
$jwt = new \Emarref\Jwt\Jwt();
try {
  $serializedToken = $jwt->serialize($token, $encryption);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  slack($subject, $e, 'CS1');
}
```

the following error is generated during the cron run:

```
 RuntimeException: No private key available for encryption. in 
 /projects/cron/jobs/vendor/emarref/jwt/src/Encryption/Asymmetric.php:35
```

the script connects to Box.com retrieves a csv and imports to a MySQL db.

Hope I provided enough.

Comment: Hello, with which user did you run the cron? Maybe the file that contain `privateKey` could not be read or found by the `cron user`.

Comment: it's owned by user 'cstools' not by cron - let me try changing to user. thank you

Comment: reported back that owner of the running script is also cstools